# Inserting array variable for CanvasJS chart

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, canvasjs

I'm currently working on a website for a family member that needs a simple calculator and graph to go along with it. I have a javascript function that is taking in 3 inputs:
total, Interest Rate and Months.
These 3 variables take in user inputs and calculates them which is working.
so I'm putting in the `total` variable and `monthDisplay` variable inside an array (var investment = [];)

and then inserting the variables into that array in a for loop

I tried using alert(investment[2][1]); just to see if data was going into array which it is

What isn't working is my chart. I just get a empty chart with no data. am I inserting the variable incorrectly?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>

  <script type = "text/javascript" src ="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js" > </script> 
  <h2> Return of Investment Calculator </h2> 
  <label> Initial Investment: </label> <input id="amount" value="500" min="1">
  <label> Interest( % ): </label> <input id="ratePerMonth" value="3" min="1.0" Max="100.0"> 
  <label> Months: </label> <input id="numberOfMonths" value="3">

  <button onclick = "calculate()" > Calculate </button> 
  <p id="display"> </p>

  <script type = "text/javascript" >

  function calculate() {
    //Beginning of user input values
    amount = document.getElementById("amount").value; //obtain initial investment
    ratePerMonth = document.getElementById("ratePerMonth").value; // rate increase per month
    numberOfMonths = document.getElementById("numberOfMonths").value; // no. of months
    //End of user input values



    // Calculator Down Below
        var investment = [];
    var text = "";
    var month = new Date().getMonth();
    var monthHolder = Number(month + 1);

    var total = amount;
    var additionalRate = 0;
    for (var i = -1; i < numberOfMonths; i++) { //Start of loop for compound

      switch (monthHolder) { //switching getMonth function to literal strings
        case 1:
          monthDisplay = "January";
          break;
        case 2:
          monthDisplay = "February";
          break;
        case 3:
          monthDisplay = "March";
          break;
        case 4:
          monthDisplay = "April";
          break;
        case 5:
          monthDisplay = "May";
          break;
        case 6:
          monthDisplay = "June";
          break;
        case 7:
          monthDisplay = "July";
          break;
        case 8:
          monthDisplay = "August";
          break;
        case 9:
          monthDisplay = "September";
          break;
        case 10:
          monthDisplay = "October";
          break;
        case 11:
          monthDisplay = "November";
          break;
        case 12:
          monthDisplay = "December";
      };

      text += "Current Amount " + parseFloat(total).toFixed(2) + "Rate: " + ratePerMonth + "% Month: " + monthDisplay + "<br>";
      //inserting data

      investment.push([
        monthDisplay,total
      ]);
      //end of data insert
      additionalRate = total * ratePerMonth / 100;
      total = Number(additionalRate) + Number(total);

      if (monthHolder < 12) {
        monthHolder++;
      } else {
        monthHolder = 1;
      }
    }
    // chartInvestment.render();
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = text;
alert(investment[2][1]);

    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
      title: {
        text: "Investment Chart"
      },
      data: [{
        type: "line",
        datapoints: investment
      }]
    });
    chart.render();
  }

  </script>

  <div id = "chartContainer" style = "height: 300px; width: 100%;" ></div> 
  </body> 
  </html>
```

Comment: (non-answer) Instead of switch .. do: monthDisplay = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ][monthHolder-1];

Comment: not really sure how the logic of that works. . .? if I'm obtaining the current month from today's date (which will be a number) I insert into the array of month display it will display the correct string but what about when it goes past december. nvm i just figured it out by typing this out.

Answer (score 0):

2 things:
1) The investment.push should push a non-array object:

investment.push ( {
    label:monthDisplay, y:total
  } );

2) datapoints should be dataPoints (that's a tough one)

Comment: niceee! it worked, thankyou so much! the datapoints thing was a tough one. . . wouldve never figured that one out

Comment: The only problem I'm getting now is that the chart is only retrieving the data after the first dataset. (skipping the first values that are being inserted into the array) still trying to figure this out.

Comment: Okay, I just figured it out. I set the variable total to equal itself again and it worked. Not sure if it was because it's obtaining the value from a user input and the chart just doesn't like that or what. . .

Comment: @Jimmy Nguyen You're welcome. Glad you are getting the details worked out. Please accept my answer -- I am trying for 1000 points!

Comment: I gave it a thumbs up but it says anyone below 15 ratings won't show their personal rating

Comment: . . . . . . . .

Comment: @Jimmy Nguyen  Thanks, I don't think it is obvious -- here are instructions to accept an answer: (1)Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem. (2)To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. (3)You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.  IT'S THE CHECKMARK BELOW THE UP/DOWN ARROWS.